# Spring Cloud Stream connection with RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, connection, spring-cloud-stream

have a simple Spring-Cloud-Stream project that I try to connect with RabbitMQ, It says its [connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta4tC.png) but It's not working. Did I do something wrong in the code?

**Application.properties**

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.greetingChannel.destination = greetings
server.port=8080
```

**HelloBinding interface**

```
package com.gateway.cloudstreamproducerrabbitmq;

import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;

public interface HelloBinding {

    @Output("greetingChannel")
    MessageChannel greeting();
}
```

**ProducerController**

```
package com.gateway.cloudstreamproducerrabbitmq;

import com.gateway.cloudstreamproducerrabbitmq.HelloBinding;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProducerController {

    private MessageChannel greet;

    public ProducerController(HelloBinding binding) {
        greet = binding.greeting();
    }

    @GetMapping("/greet/{name}")
    public void publish(@PathVariable String name) {
        String greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
        Message<String> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(greeting)
                .build();
        this.greet.send(msg);
    }
}
```

And last I have a **@EnableBinding(HelloBinding.class)** in the main class that starts the application.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291905/rabbitmq-exchange-with-spring-cloud-stream-doesnt-seem-to-update) or, do you see the connection on the console now? Are you sure you're looking at the right broker/cluster? Clearly the connection was established. Have you looked at the connection with `netstat`, `wireshark` etc? "not working" is never enough information.

Comment: Yes Its almost a duplicate, I wanted to describe it in a other way, after I wanted to delete the other but I could not find the delete button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup spring cloud stream with rabbitmq binder implementation you need to configure this in your pom.xml
1.

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

then you define this in your application.properties/yaml

2.

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            bindings:
                greetingChannel
                    destination: test.greeting
                    group: queue
            rabbit:
                bindings:
                    greetingChannel:
                        producer:
                            transacted: true //optional
```

3. `EnableBinding(HelloBinding.class)`
4. Inject binding and use it

```java
helloBinding.greeting().send(MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(...)
                .build());
```

5. Setup of rabbitMQ properties

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. There was a RabbitMQ process running on my PC that I didn't even know existed, It connected to that one first and not the one I had running on Docker. This fixed the problem. This solution works (if I had 1 process running) so I marked it as the solution, Thank you